# Can't overload the >> operator in Raku

Tags: overloading, operator-keyword, raku

I'm trying to overload the >> operator like this:

```
class A {}

multi sub infix:«>>»(A:D $a, Str() $b) is assoc<non> { dd $a; dd $b }
my $x = A.new;
$x >> 'output.txt';
```

But I get a compile error at line 5 that says:

```
Unsupported use of >> to do right shift.  In Raku please use: +> or ~>.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case of Rakudo's compiler being (kind of) too smart for its own good. Because there are different types of shifting operations in Raku and neither use a double arrow, the grammar used by Rakudo has `>>` set to trigger an alert for people who are used to other languages. I guess no one thought at the time that someone would make a `>>` operator which makes sense because `>>` more or less implies there might be a `<<`, which could wreak all sorts of havoc given it use as a quoting circumfix and a meta operator.

You can see the code the grammar here:
https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/9d6d8dd7a72aed698e30b6fe4b8eea62642c62c6/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L4104

Comment: There's another reason that overloading `>>` might be a bad idea: even without overloading `<<`, it could conflict with the hyper operator in some circumstances.  For example, the following is valid Raku: `(<a b>, <c d>)>>[1]  # OUTPUT: (b d)`.  This would conflict with your proposed definition.  (Which isn't to say that Rakudo is right to prevent you from doing so, but seems worth noting)

Comment: codesection: right, that's exactly what I was thinking of when I mentioned the meta operators.  I should probably separate that bit out a bit more in the answer to make it clearer.  Thankfully `>>>` works without problem though, so if you're just wanting the visual look and don't mind an extra character, that's an option

Comment: hmm I see, sounds like it's not meant to be overloaded. Would it still cause problems for other types of operands even with the sub's signature of "pinning" the left operand to only instances of class A?

Comment: cowbaymoo: generally not.  The issue if you look at the Grammar.nqp is where it has `<.sorryobs(…)>` (other tokens there don't have it).  As soon as that token is reached, it will bail at a compile, even before it has a chance to resolve whether the operators are called. This could possibly be fixed by adding in a check first to see if someone's defined a custom infix, etc, but because of the polysemy of `>>`, I'd avoid it even if it were fixed to be possible.  It's like trying to make `)` an infix.... you could but…

Comment: I'm with @ user0721090601 on the various existing meanings of `>>` in various syntax slots strongly arguing against it being overridable. Maybe it belongs in [`%categorically-won't-work`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/aa1b3ed32f87580b2b03eac95a774ee67c5df7b8/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L4524)?